# How to send an email from a windows *.bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am writing a windows batch to get the cpu utilization and check for condition is value is greater than 80. if cpu util greater than 80 , i should get a mail.

Could you please help. i use `wmic cpu get "LoadPercentage" | find /V "LoadPercentage"`

Comment: Your command works fine, so are you really just trying to send an email if it's over 80?

Comment: thanks Bali..yes i need to check for condition 80 and if it's more than 80 i should get email..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a 3rd party app to send an email, you could use [blat](http://www.blat.net/), then the rest of the batch would look like this

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic cpu get "LoadPercentage" ^| find /V "LoadPercentage"') do (
set p=%%a
goto :BREAK
)

:BREAK
if %p% geq 80 blat -params
```

You would need to replace the `-params` with `blat`'s actual arguments, which you can find [here](http://www.blat.net/syntax/syntax.html).

Comment: Where you do echo it? If you echo it after `:BREAK` it should work fine.

Comment: It works ok for me, are you doing the compare after the `BREAK`?